# XPath: select a node based on another node?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

Consider the following `XML`:

```
<Items>
    <Item>
        <Code>Test</Code>
        <Value>Test</Value>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Code>MyCode</Code>
        <Value>MyValue</Value>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Code>AnotherItem</Code>
        <Value>Another value</Value>
    </Item>
</Items>
```

I would like to select the `Value` node of the `Item` that has the `Code` node in with the value `MyCode`. How would I go about using `XPath`?

I've tried using `Items/Item[Code=MyCode]/Value` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Try setting MyCode in astring like this "MyCode", and if it is possible I would recommend using [Linq-to-XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx).

Comment: This "XML" is a mess - now well-formed!

Comment: @alexbrn: The bad XML may well be part of the problem, so should be in the answer (in this case).  I've addressed it in my answer, for example.  I suggest leaving the question how it was asked.

Comment: Changed the XML. My XML is a little bit more complex :P. Was just a typo.

Comment: Sorry about that.  Please edit again, and I won't "fix" the changes :)  Make sure you take care of the `Value` end tags too - right now they're `Code` end tags.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your XML data is wrong.  The `Value` tag doesn't have correct matching closing tags, and your `Item` tags don't have matching closing tags (`</Item>`).

As for your XPath, try enclosing the data you want to match in quotes:

```
const string xmlString =
@"<Items>
    <Item>
        <Code>Test</Code>
        <Value>Test</Value>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Code>MyCode</Code>
        <Value>MyValue</Value>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Code>AnotherItem</Code>
        <Value>Another value</Value>
    </Item>
</Items>";

var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlString);
XmlElement element = (XmlElement)doc.SelectSingleNode("Items/Item[Code='MyCode']/Value");
Console.WriteLine(element.InnerText);
```

Comment: It seems that the quotes are the issue.

Comment: Yes, without the quotes it tries to compare the value of the node Code, to the value of the node MyCode. As expected it doesn't find a node called MyCode.

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
/Items/Item[Code="MyCode"]/Value
```

Assuming you fix-up your XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Items>
  <Item>
    <Code>Test</Code>
    <Value>Test</Value>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Code>MyCode</Code>
    <Value>MyValue</Value>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Code>AnotherItem</Code>
    <Value>Another value</Value>
  </Item>
</Items>
```