# Select a node based on value of another node using an xsl predicate

Tags: xml, sharepoint, xslt, xpath, predicates

Similar problem to this question:
[XPath: select a node based on another node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203666/xpath-select-a-node-based-on-another-node)

The object is to select a node based on the value of a sibling node-in this case the Pagetitle node based on the value of the Pagetype node.

xpaths:

```
/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row/@Title
/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row/@Pagetype
/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row/@Pagetitle
```

This xsl isn't returning anything:

```
<xsl:value-of select= "/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[Pagetype='Parent']/@Pagetitle" />
```

Sample xml:

```
<dsQueryResponse>
       <Rows>
            <Row>
               <Title>1</Title>
               <Pagetype>Parent</Pagetype>
               <Pagetitle>title of page</Pagetitle>
            </Row>
        </Rows>
</dsQueryResponse>
```

The goal is to have the values of Pagetitle returned if they have a Pagetype value of "Parent".

Comment: Please show us a sample of the input XML and explain which nodes you want to select. Your current predicate `[Pagetype='Parent']` checks for child element(s) of the name `Pagetype` having the value `Parent`.

Comment: @Martin  Added sample of xml and tried to clarify the nodes I want to select.

Answer (score 3):

The @ sign denotes attributes of a node. So if you want to return the value of the attribute Pagetitle where the Pagetype attribute is equal to Parent, it should read:

```
<xsl:value-of select= "/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[@Pagetype='Parent']/@Pagetitle" />
```

A helpful resource I use to test my XPATH is http://www.xmlme.com/XpathTool.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link. That will come in handy. I added a snippet of the xml to clarify. Pagetype and Pagetitle are both elements/nodes and have no attributes. I guess I get confused at to when the @ should be used. The xpath Sharepoint Designer spits out includes it for the Pagetile element.

Comment: @_Aaron: Seems the OP added the source XML after your answer and there is no `Pagetype` attribute in it.

Answer (score 0):

**With the provided XML document use**:

```
/*/*/*[Pagetype = 'Parent']/Pagetitle
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select="/*/*/*[Pagetype = 'Parent']/Pagetitle"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<dsQueryResponse>
       <Rows>
            <Row>
               <Title>1</Title>
               <Pagetype>Parent</Pagetype>
               <Pagetitle>title of page</Pagetitle>
            </Row>
        </Rows>
</dsQueryResponse>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and all (in this case just one) selected nodes are output**:

```
<Pagetitle>title of page</Pagetitle>
```

Comment: I tried that and the output is still nothing. Even a simple value-of returns nothing. It does all work if I filter with xsl:ifs and don't use predicates, so I'm pretty sure the xpaths are correct. Maybe it's something to do with the way Sharepoint reads the xsl.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I understand the problem: Find each Row with a child element Pagetype of 'Parent', display value of child element Pagetitle.

My solution: Create a node set of all Rows that fulfill the criteria then select value of child element Pagetitle.

```
<xsl:for-each select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[Pagetype='Parent']">
    <xsl:value-of select="Pagetitle" />
</xsl:for-each>
```